# nativeDroid focused text input bug?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, nativedroid

I'm using this page block in JQM with nativeDroid theme

```
<div data-role="page" id="add" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle='false'>
            <h1>Add City</h1>
            <a href="#list"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
            <a id="cityAdd" href="#list"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <div class="ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
                        <input id="cityName" type="text" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Enter city..." />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div class="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle='false'>
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>
```

My problem is focused text input. In this case header and footer change their position and size. It causes added class **.ui-fixed-hidden**. I've tried override it, but in css is too much dependencies and it hasn't any effect.

Did anyone have this problem?

Thanks for answers

Comment: You mean when you focus text input it adds ui-fixed-hidden class to  header and footer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following CSS seems to work:

```
.ui-header.ui-fixed-hidden {
    padding: 0;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.ui-fixed-hidden a{
    margin-top: 1px !important;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/aay52/5/)**

Comment: thanks! I've added same fix to footer and it's OK :)